# SHARP AR5316E DRIVER?

Tags: drivers, printing

Does everyone knows, how to get Driver for Sharp AR5316E for Ubuntu 12.04.

I have tried downloading for AR-161 PPD file also, but it also does not works.

My presumption, Can I install through Wine with Driver downloaded for XP version.. Will this work...?

Also how could I use it for Network enabled printing, as this is also a network printer.

Assad

Answer (score 1):

> > My presumption, Can I install through Wine with Driver downloaded for XP version.. Will this work...?

No, you can not install a driver through Wine.

Comment: This does not answer the second portion of the question, related to the njetwork printing. It could possibly be accessed remotely through Ubuntu.